Flutter app Build failed with an exception of gradle minSdk
I've working on a flutter app project specifically for android release but when launching app, suddenly came accross this error. I tried what's written in recommended solution but it's not working.
The build tends to fail because of minSdk version being low.
I recently added Firebase cli and Firebase configuration etc to add backend to my app and after doing all that it gave this error but It also occurred in my previous projects also where I didn't use firebase.
When I paste the minsdk text in build.grade file, it shows error and nothing happens.
Sorry if I didn't provide full information, as it is my first time writing a question on SO.
I'm giving the full error(Debug Console) message here :-
<project-path>Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:firebase_auth] J:\flutter_projects\messaging_app\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 21
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 21,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:firebase_auth] J:\flutter_projects\messaging_app\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 21
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 21,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ The plugin firebase_auth requires a higher Android SDK version.                               │
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file                                            │
│ J:\flutter_projects\messaging_app\android\app\build.gradle:                                   │
│ android {                                                                                     │
│   defaultConfig {                                                                             │
│     minSdkVersion 23                                                                          │
│   }                                                                                           │
│ }                                                                                             │
│                                                                                               │
│ Following this change, your app will not be available to users running Android SDKs below 23. │
│ Consider searching for a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the     │
│ Android SDK instead.                                                                          │
│ For more information, see:                                                                    │
│ https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration          │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

After pasteing the given/recommended code in error message into gradle.build it gave me error in the file and does not tend to solve anything. I've looked it on chatGpt but its solutions doesnt seem to work at all.

This question is similar to: My Flutter App is not running after adding cloud_firebase package. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error message doesnt mention the role of Firebase in the build being failed but it failed after adding Firebase configurations so I mentioned it.

Hey , It's due to the Firebase , there are many dependencies & plugins available , which cause us to change build script of our build files..

Hey CrazyFlutterDev
Why The Problem Occured -
It's saying in error message itself , the plugin firebase-auth requires your app's minSDK should be 23 , because this plugin uses any features (meaning every updated SDK version , you get new Components i.e classes , Interfaces , Methods) which are not available in SDK version below 23 (i.e 21 in our case ) .
Solution Approached -
You should search only for minSDK in your build file & upgrade it to 23 rather than copy pasting whole thing , what has been written in Flutter Fix Window .

If you are using flatter 2.9+ you can just change the versions in local.properties file as:
sdk.dir=/Users/macbookbro/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/macbookbro/development/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

# Android versions
flutter.minSdkVersion=23
flutter.targetSdkVersion=35
flutter.compileSdkVersion=35

There is a good answer from this link: Flutter : How to change Android minSdkVersion in Flutter Project?
Or in the file:
"YourProjectPath"/android/app/build.gradle
Add /or modify the following:
defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

It's strange that mine wasn't picking up flutter.minSdkVersion
